# How to analyze size of files in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I have reached free storage limit of Dropbox and need to delete the files to make space.

Is there a way one can analyze the size of files on Dropbox using its web interface?

I can do it using Windows Explorer on desktop but I have not synced it with my new PC. So I wanted to delete some files before syncing.

Comment: Guess what the file size can be by it's type and name and if you think it's a big file, then try downloading it (but just try) and the file size should be displayed in the download list.

Comment: API? - Does something prevent a simple API script that for example, reported total storage used by photos, videos, etc, across all folders?  Downloading a terabyte local to use file utils has a lot of negatives.

Answer (score 20):

In the web interface click repeatedly the second column header, i.e. `Type` until it shows `Size` - then you will see the size of all the items in the current folder.

#### Update:

In the latest version it is now a drop-down that you can click and select **Size**.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty useless as only size of files is shown and not size of folders.

Comment: @Piotr: does your desktop file manager show the size of folders? The web interface is not the main UI, if you need more control install the Dropbox client, sync everything and then manage the files from your desktop.

Comment: Had a similar issue, found the official help page suggesting this answer https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/319

Comment: @ccpizza The OP said: "So I wanted to delete some files before syncing." So, this is probably not a viable solution for him.

Comment: You can now select "Calculate size" for multiple folders at once. Select multiple folders using for example shift and then click on the three dots on top (to the right of the delete button). If you have any file in your selection the option will not appear!

Answer (score 9):

This is (currently) not possible using the web interface.

I'd recommend going through and deleting things you don't need in each folder, perhaps sorting them into folders such as "Keep", "Not Sure" then use selective sync with your PC to only sync the files you need. Though this is not very practical on the web interface as you cannot move around files by drag and drop. Downloading everything to your desktop is your best chance of sorting the files in your Dropbox.

Apart from traffic caps imposed by your ISP or limited local hard drive space I can't think of any reason why you would not download the whole thing and sort it there.

Of course you can always get one of your family or friends to accept an invite to join Dropbox from you to gain a 500mb bonus.

Comment: It is already possible to move files/foldes using drag-n-drop. Just try it.

Comment: In my case the problem is that it won't sync locally before I either upgrade or magically figure out what shared file got so big in the web interface.

Answer (score 8):

I highly recommend [unclouded](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.unclouded) which is only for android phones. At the time of this writing it is a very new app but under my tests it worked perfectly(it's even, dare I say it, pretty beautiful) but to install it you have to join their group. There are really easy instructions at http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-unclouded-t2825327, it takes only about one minute.

This does exactly what you are asking for, my only caveat(that the developer really couldn't fix) is that you are giving him permissions to all your files. I'm not super paranoid and he says he only takes the file names and sizes but it's something to consider. If you have unencrypted, personal files, I might not use it. But, really, you shouldn't be storing any important files in the plain anyway so it shouldn't be a problem :).

Comment: On iOS you can try AirFile. It is bogged with ads but does calculate folder sizes. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airfile-cloud-manager-for/id560145740?mt=8

Comment: Same as this answer https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-the-size-of-a-folder-in-Dropbox

Answer (score 2):

I've created a bookmarklet for this, using their exposed `INLINE_JS.Browse.files`:

```
javascript:
(function() {
  var kb = INLINE_JS.Browse.files.reduce(function(kb, file) {
    return kb + file.bytes/1000;
  }, 0);
  var units = ['kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb'], unit = units.shift(), size = kb;
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    if (size < 1000) {
      break;
    }
    size /= 1000;
    unit = units.shift();
  }
  alert('Folder size: ' + (Math.round(size*1000)/1000) + ' ' + unit);
})();
```

Copy it into a bookmark's URL and hit it.

You run it in a folder and it tells you the combined size of all files in that folder. It doesn't count subfolders and it doesn't work recursively. And it might break at any time, because their JS changes a lot.

Comment: Replace the third line with `var kb = Browse.files.reduce(function(kb, file) {` to make the script work.

Comment: How would I run the script? I tried going into Javascript Console from the dropbox tab and pasting the code there. I got `ReferenceError: Browse is not defined`. I'm on Chrome v39 (x64).

Comment: @ShashwatBlack Yes, it doesn't work anymore. Looks like they changed UI to React/Backbone etc and now `Browse` isn't exposed anymore.

Comment: So perhaps delete this answer...

Comment: I've fixed it. It's now `INLINE_JS.Browse.files`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a lucky workaround.

On my Android mobile and tablet I use the app File Manager (Rhythm Software) which enables me to configure Dropbox (among other services) as a network drive (there are several other file managers that will do this). If I access Dropbox via File Manager I can select a folder as if it were on the mobile itself, click Details, and the app tells me the folder size and the number of files that are in it (not just the number of sub folders). The Dropbox mobile app itself won't do this, let alone the desktop version, as everyone has discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Just click on one of the files into your folders, then move rapidly up or down with the arrow from keyboard. If you look at the top-right corner of the screen , at the end of the toolbar, you can see the size of each files.

Comment: Note that this option on works for files and NOT for folders.  Best way is still to install and sync at least until Dropbox offers us the option to display directory and file size within the file listings.

Comment: Checked now, and info on File size showes in the top right corner when you click om it!

Comment: The above comment refers to using the up down/arrow key to highlight a FILE. Open a folder then use the arrow key to move up and down on the files contained in it. When you do this the highlighted FILE will show with its size in a banner across the top just under the dropbox search window. This does not work for a Folder. You can only see the individual File sizes contained **in** a Folder. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on file and select `Previous versions`.

Now it will show you the file size !

Comment: That's going to be impractical to do with hundreds or thousands of files.

Comment: But works for a few of them

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is if you have Dropbox synced with your desktop or laptop.  Go to Windows Explorer (My Computer) and go to the Dropbox library or folder on the computer and you can see folder sizes by right clicking and selecting properties.  Any changes or deletions you make will be reflected in the web client of Dropbox.

Comment: The OP stated that he knows how to do it on his PC, but hasn't added the client to sync because he wants to delete files before doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the arrow at the middle which might read something else (if not "size").
Then click the 3 dotten button at the right and select "Calculate Size" of any folder. It'll calculate the size and reorder it depending on the size (ascending or descending).

Enjoy!

[image: dropbox size order calculate]

Answer (score -2):

In the Windows directory, right click on a folder in Dropbox and choose Properties.  It will show the folder size.